# Bootstrap Responsible glitch?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need help cause i dont know why  this happening but span coming true menu, also giving here my code and screens this happening on whole website

menu is  :  col-md-6
span is : col-md-1
[image]
[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<header>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <a href="../pages/uvod.php" class="hvr-shrink"><img src="../res/logo/StylMejker_logo.png" alt="StylMejker Logo" style="margin: 0 0 25px 0;" ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <nav class="nav row">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li class="aktualna"><a href="../pages/uvod.php">Úvod</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/o_mne.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">O mne</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/sluzby.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Služby</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/referencie.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Referencie</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/styloviny.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Štýloviny</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/media.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Média</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/kontakt.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="clearfix"></section>
<main>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        test
    </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you put those icons inside the nav container?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <header>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <a href="../pages/uvod.php" class="hvr-shrink"><img src="../res/logo/StylMejker_logo.png" alt="StylMejker Logo" style="margin: 0 0 25px 0;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <nav class="nav row">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="aktualna"><a href="../pages/uvod.php">Úvod</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/o_mne.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">O mne</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/sluzby.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Služby</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/referencie.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Referencie</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/styloviny.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Štýloviny</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/media.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Média</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/kontakt.php" class="hvr-overline-from-center">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li class="text-center"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="clearfix"></section>
  <main>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      test
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: great :3 i never thinked about this solution :o

Comment: @PatrikHorváth =D np

Comment: @PatrikHorváth wait, I just realize that there is a problem in your html, for `col-xx-x` to work you need class `row` in the parent container for example `<header class="row">`.

Comment: but container-fluid is same as row or ?

Comment: @PatrikHorváth not the same, source here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/094b3a129349a41b1319b0870fb3daa9459b7284/scss/_grid.scss#L18-L44. `row` is required for `col-` to work.